# SQL, соглашение об именовании таблиц

Tags: sql, postgresql

хотел спросить про соглашение об именовании в SQL в частности таблиц. Они должны быть с маленькой буквы написаны или с большой? Есть ли разница? Интересно еще как для PostgreSQL.

Comment: *соглашение об именовании в SQL в частности таблиц. Они должны быть с маленькой буквы написаны или с большой?* Во всех примерах в PostgreSQL Documentation все имена (баз, таблиц, полей и пр.) пишутся исключительно в нижнем регистре. *Есть ли разница?* Иногда есть (если квотировано), иначе нет. См. [Lexical Structure - Identifiers and Key Words](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Насколько мне известно, единого описанного где-то соглашения у
*PostgreSQL* нет.  Фактические соглашения можно увидеть в
[документации](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/index.html).

Многие фреймворки типа *Ruby on rails* ожидают определённое
именование в БД, и если вы работаете с ними, то лучше его и
придерживаться.

Также многие используют
[*Gitlab SQL Style Guide*](https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/business-ops/data-team/sql-style-guide/) или
[*SQLStyle.Guide*](https://www.sqlstyle.guide/).